# how to hide previous one when showing next one with jquery?

Tags: jquery

<s>I ain't find the vertical news scroller for joomla 2.5 So I wanted to make my own.</s>

Firstly I have hidden first two lists and then I wanted to show next list when clicked but I'm doing wrong

```
$('ul li').slice(2).hide();
$('#up').on('click',function(){
    $('ul li').slice(3).hide();    
});
```

[here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UtEyf/)

I also wanted to show the next list and hide the previous first list. How can I do?

**Edit**

Okay now I have made working like using this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UtEyf/1/)

```
var countnews = 3;
$('ul li').slice(countnews).hide();
$('#up').on('click',function(){
    $('ul li').show();    
    $('ul li').slice(countnews++).hide();
});
```

Now, how can I hide the previous one when showing next one?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? This code is really weird...

Comment: when clicked to up next li should be displayed and previous displayed first one should hide

Comment: And you want it to show always 3 items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var start = 0;
var end = 3;
var len=$('li').length;
$('ul li').hide().slice(start, end).show();
$('#up').on('click',function(){
    if(end<len)
    {
       start++;end++;
       $('ul li').hide().slice(start, end).show();    
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UtEyf/4/)

For **down**

```
$('#down').on('click',function(){
    if(start>0)
    {
       start--;end--;
       $('ul li').hide().slice(start, end).show();    
    }
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UtEyf/6/)

Updated **code** with **animation**

```
$('#up').on('click',function(){
    if(end<len)
    {
        $('ul li').slice(start, end).slideUp(500);  
        start++;end++;
        setTimeout(function(){
           $('ul li').hide().slice(start, end).slideDown(500); 
        },500);

    }
});
$('#down').on('click',function(){
    if(start>0)
    {
         $('ul li').slice(start, end).slideUp(500);  
         start--;end--;
         setTimeout(function(){
            $('ul li').hide().slice(start, end).slideDown(500); 
         },500);
    }
});
```

[Animated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UtEyf/10/)

Comment: @C-Link you can use `fadeIn()` for this see demo http://jsfiddle.net/UtEyf/7/

Read fadeIn docs http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn

Comment: I wanted to give scroll effect so I tried slideUp and slideDown but didn't work and tried slideToggle that works but it's not the way I want

Comment: in your fiddle it's sliding up to down but I wanted to make when one is hide that should be hidden in a way that is sliding up and when next one is shown that should be sliding up

Answer (score 1):

How about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UtEyf/2/)

```
var start = 0;
var end = 2;

$('ul li').hide().slice(start, end ).show();
$('#up').on('click',function(){
    //$('ul li').show();
    start++;end++;
    //alert(start)
    $('ul li').hide().slice(start, end ).show();    
});
```

Update fiddle to work with both `up` and `down` . [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UtEyf/3/)

Answer (score 0):

There's very nice implementation of such behavior in jQueryUi named [Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) - try to use it (or just check the source as a base for your specific needs)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give script like this

```
  $(document).ready(function(){     
        $('ul li').slice(3).hide();
        $("#up").click(function(){
            $('ul li').show();
            $('ul li').slice(0,3).hide()
            //alert('dk');

         });    

        })
```